# Why is my OpenGL 4.1 shader not working on OS X Macbook ( works on Linux )?

Tags: opengl, shaders, macos, porting

I've recently rebuild shaders for my program and it stopped "working" ( black screen ) on OS X ( El Capitan ), but it's ok on Linux. What could be the cause?

There are no shader compilation errors, and here is my shader code:

https://github.com/Marqin/YuriaViewer/blob/master/vertex.glsl

Keep in mind that this software worked on El Capitan with OpenGL 4.1 before shader rewrite. Here are my glfw hints:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

My program also is checking for `GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` and it's available on my Macbook ( Macbook Air 2013 mid ).

EDIT1:

I've "debugged" it a little and it looks that `i` is always lesser than `vis` on OS X, that's why it's black.

EDIT2:

I made a simple test - I've typed all uniform values in shader by hand and now it wasn't black, but I've got some gibberish on screen. Then I've changed every `dvec3` and `dvec2` to float versions and it showed nice fractal. So it looks like `double` is not working on OS X. But how can it be? It's saying that `GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` is available and it even doesn't complain when I request it in vertex shader.

EDIT3:

It works on iMac with R9 M395. So it's problem with Intel hardware ( or problem with OS X Intel driver ).

Comment: What did you change it from? Can you break it down to see where the problem is? For example, if you just use the output of `color()` do you see anything? If so, then the problem's probably with the `hsv2rgb()` function. Otherwise it's probably with the `color()` function. Also, are you producing any `NaN` or `Inf`s? There's a lot of divides in there. Are any of them dividing by 0? Different drivers handle that differently.

Comment: I've "debugged" it a little, and it looks that `i` is always `<` than `vis`, so it's always black. About 0 - w, h, zoom, posX, posY are never 0 before sending them to GPU. Maybe Uniform Buffer works differently on OS X and shader sees some 0's there on OS X?

Comment: Maybe OS X drivers have problems with loops? Or it's abs doesn't work with doubles ( it should work according to 4.1 specification ).

Comment: @user1118321, it looks that `double` is the culprist.

Comment: I've updated question, because it's working on Mac with AMD GPU ( and my Nvidia linux ) so it's probably problem with Intel.